# How to speed up Django admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model with a table that has around 5 million records. Currently django admin is very slow for the list display page. It can take a minute or more for the page to load.

Is there a way to optimize the list display page? And make it load under 10 seconds? Thanks in advance.

**models.py**

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token)
    alert = models.ForeignKey(Alert)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_processed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    error_sending = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.id )
```

**admin.py**

```
class AppNotification(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['is_sent','is_processed','error_sending']

    #
    list_display = ('token_code','is_sent','is_processed')

    #
    search_fields = ('token','alert')

    #
    list_select_related = ('alert', 'token')

    #
    list_per_page = 30

admin.site.register(Notification,AppNotification)
```

Django Version 1.6

**Solution**

```
class AppNotification(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('token','alert')

    fields = ['is_sent','is_processed','error_sending','token','alert']

    #
    list_display = ('id','is_sent','is_processed','error_sending')

    #
    search_fields = ['token__token']

    #
    list_per_page = 50

admin.site.register(Notification,AppNotification)
```

Comment: You have the solution: `list_per_page` !! Would that not work ? Pagination is the most obvious way of addressing these issues

Comment: Unfortunately list_per_page does not make any difference. 
It is very slow because the table has more than 5 million records. Other django admin pages with less number of records, load very fast.

Comment: Please post the omitted Notification model code.

Comment: Please post the Meta Class of the Notifaction Model. The default ordering of the Admin is important too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably the join on the `token` foreign key. You may want to remove that `token_code` from the `list_display`, if possible and completely remove your `list_select_related` property,

At the very least, remove the `'alert'` from `list_select_related` property, since you don't even use it in the list view.

Answer (score 2):

Remove:

```
list_select_related = ('alert', 'token')
```

list_select_related will call select_related. But looking up all related alerts an tokens is redundant.

Why did you truncate the Notification model?

```
# ... <-- Maybe there is inefficient logic over here!
```

Answer (score 1):

Add show_full_result_count = False

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/)